# main.lua:25:attempt to call method'setanchorPoint'(a nil value)stack traceback:main.lua25:in maiin chunk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am geeting an error:  main.lua:25:attempt to call method'setanchorPoint'(a nil value)stack traceback:main.lua25:in maiin chunk. Please tell me how can I use anchorPoint. And how to resolve this issue

```
--constants
_H = display.contentHeight;
_W = display.contentWidth;
mRand = math.random;
o = 0;
time_remain = 10;
time_up = false;
total_orbs = 20;
ready = false;
--Prepare sounds to be played or accessed
local soundtrack = audio.loadStream("media/soundtrack.caf");
local pop_sound = audio.loadSound("media/pop.caf");
local win_sound = audio.loadSound("media/win.caf");
local fail_sound = audio.loadSound("media/fail.caf");

local display_txt = display.newText("Wait", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 16*2);
display_txt.xScale = .5; display_txt.yScale = .5;
display_txt:setanchorPoint(display.BottomLeftanchorPoint);
display_txt.x = 20; display_txt.y = _H-20;
```

Comment: I can't find function `setanchorPoint` in corona documentation

Comment: I just replaced anchor with the reference object.Here is the code. Please look in to it.

Comment: local display_txt = display.newText("Wait", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 16*2);
display_txt.xScale = .5; display_txt.yScale = .5;
display_txt:setanchorPoint(display.BottomLeftanchorPoint);
display_txt.x = 20; display_txt.y = _H-20;

Comment: edit your question. don't add code in comments... would you please read [ask]? its your habit of not reading manuals which got you here in the first place. so if you're not reading the Corona manual, would you please at least read StackOverflow's guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to use anchor points in Corona, the usual approach is to refer to the Corona manual....

[Corona Anchor Guide](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/transform-anchor.html#anchors)

> **Anchors**
>
> The anchor of an object controls how geometry is positioned
> relative to the object's origin. **This is specified via** the
> **object.anchorX and object.anchorY properties**.

They even give examples....

You cannot just invent function names and wonder why you get error messages for callinig them.